# Node buffer doesn't properly download file?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I'm successfully sending a `get` request that generates a pdf on the server, which I now want to send back to client and download it on their browser. The npm pdf generating library I'm using is called [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) and has the following options:

```
pdf.create(html).toFile([filepath, ]function(err, res){
  console.log(res.filename);
});

pdf.create('<h1>Hi</h1>').toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
  console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
});
```

When I use the `toFile` option, the file gets correctly generated, however, when I use the `toBuffer` option and send that back to the user, the resulting pdf is blank.

I send the buffer to the user from my ajax handler like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
    pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=panda.pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.send(buffer)
    });
};
```

which gets received on the client here:

```
$.get('generatePdf', function(data, status) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
})
```

For some reason though the pdf that is downloaded is blank. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

My downloaded file is corrupt according to this [online pdf validator](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) with the following errors:

> Result    Document does not conform to PDF/A. Details  Validating file
>   "file (8).pdf" for conformance level pdf1.4
>
> The 'xref' keyword was not found or the xref table is malformed. The
>   file trailer dictionary is missing or invalid. The "Length" key of the
>   stream object is wrong. Error in Flate stream: data error. The
>   document does not conform to the requested standard. The file format
>   (header, trailer, objects, xref, streams) is corrupted. The document
>   does not conform to the PDF 1.4 standard.

Comment: You're not checking for any errors. `pdf.create(...).toBuffer(...)` in itself works just fine for me. Also, try opening the endpoint directly from your browser, instead of calling it through some client-side code, to rule out that it isn't the latter that's at fault.

Comment: Opening the endpoint directly from the browser? What does that mean? Sry

Comment: Open `http://yoursite/generatePdf` in the browser's location bar.

Comment: Ok, so when I open the link directly from the browser the pdf correct opens in the same tab... what can I deduce from that?

Comment: That the problem is most likely caused by your client-side code, not the server-side code. Take a look at this: http://keyangxiang.com/2017/09/01/HTML5-XHR-download-binary-content-as-Blob/

Comment: strange.. all the resources online say what I'm doing in the client side code I provided is correct.